# Asp.net MVC Linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have following two tables

```
public partial class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumId{ get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public int Artistid { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is to get Genre name in the Album's Genre column through LinQ's join query...
What I have done yet is :

```
Album a = new Album();
a.Genre = from album in db.Albums
          join genre in db.Genres on album.GenreId equals genre.GenreId
          select new { name = genre.Name };
```

But nope it's not proper, b'coz I have list on right side and cant store list to Album.Genre.

I have found one way to store result in variable for store single string to the album.genre, but however i cant do that because of the large amount of the data, it will slow down the processing.

Any other way to achieve it. Pls help...

Thank you....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thank you for your help AgentFire. It helped me a a lot in my project.

Comment: The sarcasm is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

You want something along the lines of:

```
Album a = new Album();
a.Genre = (from album in db.Albums
          join genre in db.Genres on album.GenreId equals genre.GenreId
          select new Genre { ... }).FirstOrDefault();
```